# Placing the atomic mass and number of an element...

Tags: atoms, isotope

Why are the atomic and the mass numbers of an element flipped in the textbooks relative to the periodic table?

Comment: what do you mean by flipped here

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! This is a bit unclear. Do you mean why is the info about A and Z about every element is included in "books about periodic table"? Also, it would help if you clarify what books you exactly mean.

Answer (score 1):

In the [periodic table](http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Periodic_Table_of_Elements), the largest number is indeed the atomic number. This is the number of protons. Since this defines the element, it is considered the **most important** number.

What you probably mean is 
$^A_Z\mathrm{Element}$. Here, **by convention** the lower $Z$ (from the German word *Zahl* is the atomic number, while $A$ is the sum of protons and neutrons. This defines a particular isotope. This notation is often used in the context of NMR spectroscopy ($^{13}\ce{C}$ NMR), or when radioactive decays are described:

\[\ce{^{14}_6C -> ^{14}_7N} + e^- + \bar\nu_e\]

In summary, I think this is just a set of different conventions which show that in differents contexts either the element itself or a particular isotope and its properties are considered more important.